How to redirect react router to correct path?
I am using react-router v6.
I have a question regarding to path
I have path like this
<Route path='/recipe/:id' element={<RecipePage />}>
    <Route path='/recipe/:id/ingredients' element={<Ingredients />} />
    <Route path='/recipe/:id/instructions' element={<Instructions />} />
</Route>

RecipePage component is the parent of Ingredients and Instructions.
The problem is if I remove ingredients or instructions it didn't automatically redirect to correct path which is /recipe/:id/ingredients.
How to redirect it to /recipe/:id/ingredients if the word  ingredients or instructions is missing?
RecipePage
<div>
      {data && (
        <>
          <RecipeHeader nutritionalFacts={data.nutrition} name={data.name} />
          <RecipeInfo
            instructions={data.instructions}
            image={data.thumbnail_url}
            ingredients={data.sections[0].components}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </div>

RecipeInfo
<div className='recipe-info'>
      <Outlet context={{ instructions, ingredients }} />
      <img src={image} alt='' className='recipe-img' />
    </div>

Instruction
<div className='recipe-info-container'>
      <div className='recipe-info-header'>
        <h3>INSTRUCTIONS</h3>
        <Link to={`/recipe/${id}/ingredients`} className='recipe-info-link'>
          Ingredients
        </Link>
      </div>
      {instructions.map(({ position, display_text }) => (
        <div key={position} className='recipe-info-content-container'>
          <div className='recipe-step'>{position}</div>
          <div className='recipe-text'>{display_text}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>

Ingredients
<div className='recipe-info-container'>
      <div className='recipe-info-header'>
        <h3>INGREDIENTS</h3>
        <Link to={`/recipe/${id}/instructions`} className='recipe-info-link'>
          Instructions
        </Link>
      </div>
      {ingredients.map(({ position, raw_text }) => (
        <div key={position} className='recipe-info-content-container'>
          <div className='recipe-step'>{position}</div>
          <div className='recipe-text'>{raw_text}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
</div>

